# No direct access and PSR-2

Tags: access

PSR-2 demands that a file either defines classes and functions *or* contains side-effects. Including

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
```

in all files collides with this convention. Is it safe to exclude this line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory yes. This line is designed to stop remote file inclusion. So if you're in any file that only has a class then you are effectively safe. The only component files you'd need this in are your html default.php (and any other template files). So in the html outputting files the component entry file it's absolutely compulsory and in all other files it doesn't do any harm but isn't strictly necessary

In practice we can't scan for this kind of requirement easily in our automated JED checker so we require this in every file.

So ultimately it depends if you want to be listed on JED or not. If it's a custom component then just the html output and component entry files should have it (and it's unlikely either will be adhering to PSR-2 anyhow). If it's something you are distributing on JED then yes in every file is required. I'd still err on the side of including it in every file personally whatever the use case.

I also think you're reading a bit too much into PSR-2 here - I could argue preventing direct access to a file isn't what it means as a side-effect. They mean about having the class as the only responsibility. This check is only about the file itself - yes it's not to do with the class but it's not about doing other side tasks. It's just asking if this file has been directly accessed or whether it's being included by the Joomla CMS Application

Comment: Sure, the main reason to fix all PSR-2 warnings - even if they are trivial as in this case - is to be more awake when something is wrong.

Comment: Olle Härstedt, any way you can't go with full PSR-2 and Joomla without some "hacks", reason - I need you classes to be at least vendor namespaced. @GeorgeWilson there is no reading to much into PSR-2, it's default PHPCS PSR-2 check warning message, so I believe this is not situation where meaning can be discussed as those are checker warnings.

Comment: Any plans on making Joomla components PSR-2 compatible?

Comment: Almost certainly not. We are going to add namespaces in Joomla 4, but I don't think we are going to break all outstanding PR's to go from tabs to spaces and also the _JEXEC checks will almost certainly never get removed. Other than those two items we are aiming for compliance I think

Comment: We do have our own coding standards that long predate PSR-2 https://github.com/joomla/coding-standards - so of course these will trend towards PSR-2 but given that we have support in PHPStorm for our style guide etc. There's no real rush for the project

Comment: Just been doing some check ups @OlleHärstedt you're line is from PSR 1 not PSR 2. The spec also says SHOULD NOT which gives some leeway. So honestly even if Joomla goes towards PSR-2 compliance that specific check is something we probably won't fix for security reasons

Comment: @GeorgeWilson How about avoiding this issue by adding next logic: if file have no Class declaration - check for _JEXEC; other way: check for _JEXEC check in __constructor() at least(or withing the class)? It will solve the issue I believe. Any comments? (I could try to take my time and create PR for JED Checker)

Comment: You'd also need to ensure that the class is the only thing in the file. Don't forget just because there is a class in the file doesn't guarantee there is nothing else in the file too (we can't assume people are using PSR-2 or following best practices). But yes if you can be sure that the class is the only thing in the file then it would solve the issue. I'm not on the JED team so I can't promise it would be accepted, but I can't see why it wouldn't be